# Implementing and testing a stored PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to to insert a row into APPLICANT table and to generate a warning whenever a new applicant has the same values of all attributes except applicant number (a#) as an applicant already recorded in a table APPLICANT. Pass the values of attributes through the input parameters of a stored procedure INSAPP.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSAPP(

a_num       IN  NUMBER,
a_fname     IN  VARCHAR,
a_lname     IN  VARCHAR,
a_address   IN  VARCHAR,
a_city      IN  VARCHAR,
a_state     IN  VARCHAR,    
a_phone     IN  NUMBER, 
a_fax       IN  NUMBER, 
a_email     IN  VARCHAR,    
a_acomment  IN  LONG) IS

    app_row     APPLICANT%ROWTYPE;
    FAIL EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
--VERIFY APPLICANT FNAME
    SELECT *
    INTO app_row
    FROM APPLICANT
    WHERE fname = a_fname AND
    lname = a_lname AND
    address = a_address AND
    city = a_city AND
    state = a_state  AND
    phone# = a_phone AND
    fax# = a_fax AND
    email = a_email AND
    acomment = a_acomment;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CREATING APPLICANT');
        BEGIN
            SELECT MAX(a#)+1
            INTO a_num
            FROM APPLICANT;
            INSERT INTO APPLICANT VALUES (a_num,a_fname,a_lname,a_address,a_city,a_state,a_phone,a_fax,a_email,a_acomment);
        COMMIT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('APPLICANT HAS SUCCESSFULLY ADDED');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN Fail THEN
            ROLLBACK;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
            ROLLBACK;
    END;

END;
END INSAPP;
/
```

But when i trying to execute it with this code,it give me an error message like this

- Warning: Pcedure created with compilation errors.

Then i trying to show the erros:
 - 49/1  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Did i make any mistake on the pl/sql code? Please correct me as i'm still new to pl/sql. Thanks and very appreciate that. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you execute it from sqlplus, please try

```
EXEC INSAPP ( 000001, 'PETER', 'JONES', '7 STATION ST.', 'PERTH', 'WA', 645278453, NULL, NULL, 'Job expectations ? Money, money, money, ...' );
```

or wrap it inside `begin .. end` block

```
begin
    INSAPP ( 000001, 'PETER', 'JONES', '7 STATION ST.', 'PERTH', 'WA', 645278453, NULL, NULL, 'Job expectations ? Money, money, money, ...' );
end;
/
```

UPD.
I think that you procedure is not compiled.

You cannot change value of input parameter `a_num` (by the way, it is not best to get new id for table, use sequences)

```
SELECT MAX(a#)+1
INTO a_num
FROM APPLICANT;
```

You have unnecessary `END;` after `rollback` statement in `when` section

Due to fact that compare null values always return false it is not good to search record by this condition

```
WHERE fname = a_fname AND
   lname = a_lname AND
   address = a_address AND
   city = a_city AND
   state = a_state  AND
   phone# = a_phone AND
   fax# = a_fax AND
   email = a_email AND
   acomment = a_acomment;
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for helping. I had try both method. But i still getting the same error. Yes i'm using sqlplus.

Comment: do you run in schema which contains this procedure?

Comment: One `END;` is unnecessary as @DmitryAgibov mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @DmitryAgibov now i getting Pl/SQL: ORA-00977: illegal user of Long datatype
What is the problem on long data type?

Comment: you cannot use `LONG` type in sql query

Comment: But created the acomment as LONG datatype in the Applicant table. Then other way to resolve this ?

Comment: may be better use `CLOB` or `BLOB` types?

Comment: everything is okay now, but why my pl/sql code is not verifying the condition where `fname = a_fname AND
   lname = a_lname AND
   address = a_address AND
   city = a_city AND
   state = a_state  AND
   phone# = a_phone AND
   fax# = a_fax AND
   email = a_email AND
   acomment = a_acomment;`

If lname = a_lname and so on, it should not allow to insert. But why it still can be insert the values into my table? Is my where clause had some mistake?

Comment: as I said above you pass `NULL` value and compare with `NULL` is always false, try to use `nvl` or check for `is null`  or `is not null`

Comment: Where should i put the nvl condition?

Comment: e.g. `fname = nvl(a_fname, 'NODATA')`, but it may be not best solution

Comment: if a_name is null fname will be compared with value `NODATA`